# Node.js callback never fires unless the main code is executed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

In node.js, when there is an endless loop after a function call which also gets a callback function as as parameter, the callback never fires even if the operation is completed. For example :

```
database.insert(data, function() {
    //do stuff
})

while(1) {
    //do stuff
}
```

- In the case above, the call back function with "//do stuff" in it, never fires.
  This confuses me about the fact that node.js is called asynchronous . How can it be asynchronous if it cant run callback while there is something else to do ?
- If database insertion is asynchronous even though callback function needs to wait, then how is that concurrency provided?

Thank you.

edit: typos

Comment: Asynchronous operations != concurrent operations

Comment: How so? I have dealt with many threading stuff before, and it was physically concurrent. Even if it meant the concurrency was achieved in IO level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js is single-threaded, so it can only do one thing at a time. If you are running a very cpu-intensive job, perhaps you can do it in another process using child_process?

Otherwise, and this is not really recommended, you could break up your heavy work into multiple calls of the same function and use process.nextTick(), i.e:

```
function compute() {
     // do work here
     process.nextTick(compute);
}

compute();
```

This will allow the event loop to process other tasks in between your computations.